# How to shuffle this generated (000 -999) value

Tags: php, shuffle, generate-series

Please fix it..

I want to shuffle the value that i will get from the following code.

```
<?php
for ( $i = 000; $i < 1000; $i++){
echo str_pad($i, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\r\n";
}
?>
```

Please help me by fixing the above code

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ar=range(0, 1000);
shuffle($ar);
foreach ($ar as $key => $value) {
  echo str_pad($value, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br />\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$min = 0;
$max = 999;
for ( $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++){
  echo str_pad(rand($min, $max), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you bro but i want the value in the form of 001, 002 and if about 10 then 011, 050.

With your code i'm getting 1, 2, 3 etc upto 999 i want it 001, 002 , 003 upto 999

Comment: echo str_pad(rand($min, $max), 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . "<br>";

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.